# Can't catch exception from promise

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I'm having trouble with this code:

```
fetch('/example.json')
  .then(response => Promise.all([response, response.json()])) // This line throws unhandled exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
  .then(([response, json]) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(json));
    }
    return json;
  })
  .catch(exception => {
    const error = new Map([
      [TypeError, ["There was a problem fetching the response."]],
      [SyntaxError, ["There was a problem parsing the response."]],
      [Error, JSON.parse(exception.message)]
    ]).get(exception.constructor);

    return { error };
  })
```

It works fine for the most part, but it fails when the response from the server is 200 OK, but the actual content is an HTML. I know it's an error on the server, but I just want my client to handle it right. That is, it should catch the response.json() exception with the final catch.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Calling `JSON.parse(exception.message)` regardless of the actual `exception` you are getting looks like a bad idea.

Comment: What exactly makes you think that your final `catch` doesn't handle the exception?

Comment: Looking further into it, the catch does execute too. But, Chrome with devtools open stops execution on the response.json() (after resuming execution, it executes the catch). Is it normal devtools behaviour to stop the execution before the catch happens?

Comment: I think yes, it stops on the line that throws the exception/rejects the promise, not only on the `catch` where you might have set your breakpoint.

Comment: This code is so odd it makes sense that it would be troublesome. The `Promise.all()` is inappropriate at that location and is likely the cause of all the woes here.  The first argument to `Promise.all()` is the resolved Promise from the request, hence does nothing, the second is the normally expected operation that resolves (in this case) to parsed JSON. The `if(!response.ok)` conditional code should be placed within the first `.then()` as that is the appropriate time to deal with the response. Then the return statement upon a 'good' condition should be `return response.json()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem thanks to the comment from Bergi.

> Calling JSON.parse(exception.message) regardless of the actual exception you are getting looks like a bad idea.

That line on the catch was causing a second exception inside the catch, thus causing all the trouble.

About the devtool stoping even when "Pause on caught exceptions" is unchecked, looks like that doesn't apply to Promise catches: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465666